# Pdf download as blank from link even after giving headers also in request

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, python-requests

The request response is 200, but still, the file is downloaded as blank. Please help to solve this challenge.

```py
import requests
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get(link, stream=True, headers=HEADERS)
with open(output_filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: The PDF is rendered on that page but your URL is not a direct hyperlink to the PDF document

Comment: @DarkKnight then how to do it

Comment: You'll need to find out where the PDFs are. Examination of the HTML / JavaScript may help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ninja_haze_developer2484 Why did you delete the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a form in the html page. You can submit that form, or get key/encoded string and send request for pdf with new link/url.

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "url1"

# get key from html page -> <form> -> <script> {encodedString = dfsfsdfs}</script>
with requests.Session() as session:
    res = session.get(url)
soup = bs(res.text, 'html.parser')
form = soup.select_one('form#SummaryForm > script', string=re.compile('encodedString'))

key = re.findall(r"encodedString = '([^']*)'", form.text)[0]
# fid from url string
fid = re.findall(r'fundid=(\d+)', url)[0]   

# For the download link, searched for xhr, by going to inspect devtools, -> Network tabs, and filter by fetch/xhr.
link = f'new_url_to_pdf?key={key}&fid={fid}'
output_filename = 'file.pdf'
r = requests.get(link)
with open(output_filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

There is an alternative to this which is [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) and [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/). Since you need very less interaction with browser, you can try requests-html.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


url = 'url2'
script = """
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    iframe = document.selector('iframe:not([style*="display: none"])')[0].click();
    e = $.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 83; // S
    e.ctrlKey = true; // CTRL
    $(document).trigger(e);
})
"""

session = HTMLSession()
res = session.get(url)
res.html.render(sleep=2, keep_page=True, script=script)
```

It will automatically download webdriver when you first run the code. So, first run might take a little time, another run will be faster.

Edit 2:
`requests-html` doesn't work due to presence of iframe

Comment: how you get the link data

Comment: change (\w+) to (.+) in `key`. initially it only showed alphanumeric value to I assumed it be so.

Comment: for download link, searched for xhr, by going to inspect devtools, -> Network taps, filter by fetch/xhr. There you will see something like `pro?key=I9...`. Click on it and on to side, select Headers

Comment: You might need to hit F5 or `Ctrl+R` if you already loaded the page.

Comment: how to write code such that it will work for all the links

Comment: on both above site, you can find request link as I mentioned above. link will require some key which you can search in html or scripts. As for code that will work on any/every site, such doesn't exist. Every site is built differently. So, there will always be some differences to scrape them.

Comment: Can we write some logic on html side to get these links automatically. Like just asking , I know your effort is commendable

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by writing logic on html side.

Comment: By using `requests`+`bs4`, you will need to get url-of-pdf through xhr/fetch for each site (not each url). **But** for your urls since the sites seem fairly similar with a download button, you could use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/interactions/#click) which has click functionality. So you write a code to pass url and click on button that says "Download" and you are done.

Comment: @DanielSabrel I failed with the key's regex. Mine is quite rough `key = re.findall(r"encodedString = '([^']*)'?", form.text)[0]`. Could I have some advice, please?

Comment: @ConstantinHong yes you are right. Didn't check that.

Comment: res.html.render(sleep=2, keep_page=True, script=script) -> failing at this point